# Как сделать чтобы после Timeout с анимацией исчезал div на чистом JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как этот код написать на чистом JavaScript?

В нем автоматом в течение 3х секунд `div` проподает:

```
setTimeout( function() {
    $('#message').fadeOut('slow');
    },  3000);
```

---

UPD Спасибо за ответы! Но у меня анимация и opacity не поможет потому, что после него остается местно на странице, а должно все пропасть.

Comment: добавил вариант с ичсезновением после opacity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если без анимации, то очень просто:

```js
    function Hide(){ // Можно создать функцию скрытия поля, чтобы при необходимости можно было с ней работать в других вызовах
        document.getElementById('message').style.display = "none";
    }
    setTimeout(Hide, 3000); //Ставим таймаут на скрытие
```

```html
<div id="message">Пурум Пум Пум</div>
```

Если хотите анимацию, что можно использовать `opacity`, но он просто делает его невидимым, но не удаляется как `display: none`, а продолжает занимать место на странице, просто невидимый.

```js
    function Hide(){
        document.getElementById('message').classList.add('slow');
    }
    setTimeout(Hide, 3000);
```

```css
    .slow {
        opacity: 0;
        transition: 2s;
    }
```

```html
<div id="message">Пурум Пум Пум</div>
```

Для плавного скрытия, а потом исчезновения, можно объединить.

```js
    function Hide1(){ // Можно создать функцию скрытия поля, чтобы при необходимости можно было с ней работать в других вызовах
        document.getElementById('message').style.display = "none";
    }
    function Hide(){
        document.getElementById('message').classList.add('slow');
    }
    setTimeout(Hide, 3000);
    setTimeout(Hide1, 5000); //Исчезает блок через 5 секунд - 3 секунды после загрузки и 2 секунды анимации.
```

```css
    .slow {
        opacity: 0;
        transition: 2s;
    }
```

```html
<div id="message">Пурум Пум Пум</div>
```

Comment: Да, успешно, спасибо. Если есть более короткий код буду признателен, а так работает

Answer (score 2):

Если вам не нужна анимация, то вполне подойдет такое решение

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.querySelector('#message').style.display = 'none';
},  3000);
```

```css
#message {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="message"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

я конечно не суперспец, но вот

```
    let test = document.getElementById("test");
setTimeout( function() {
    test.style = 'display: none'
    },  3000);
```

https://codepen.io/LordOfTime/pen/zYxgygP

можно так же выставить стиль opacity: 0, но он просто станет невидимым, или выставить height: 0, тогда не будет занимать место. и не забудь тогда установить transition